# How to apply JSLink to the custom new form of list?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, jslink, newform

I have created custom new form for list using SharePoint designer, to customize the behavior of OOTB SharePoint. The functionality which I wanted to achieve is complete but I am not seeing the option for JSLink in the settings.

Is there any way to apply JSLink to custom new form?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to attach JsLink file to your list. If you want to add to new form only - you can specify it in the settings of the default new form from the browser:

[image: Web part settings window]

Also you can choose another way like:

- Use PowerShell and specify JSLink to Content Type
- Use PowerShell and specify JSLink to Site Column or List Column
- Or deploy you custom fields or content types with JSLink specified using schema.

Here are some samples

http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013