# JSLink custom field type not working in a form created by SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt-list-view-web-part, jslink, custom-field-types, client-side-rendering

I have created a custom field type for a SharePoint 2013 list using the JSLink method. It is basically a rich text editor that uses Ckedit.js. It works fine with SharePoint's default new/edit forms for lists.

However, when I create a custom Create/Edit form for this list using SharePoint Designer, the JSLink custom field doesn't work because the javascript file is not even being loaded.

When I opened the code of the form in Sharepoint Designer, it looks like this:

```
<xsl:template name=...>
...
</xsl:template>
```

I understand it means that this is a server-rendered form, rather than a client-rendered form.

My ultimate goal is basically to create a tabbed interface for the New/Edit form, this is why I'm trying to create a custom New/Edit list form in Sharepoint Designer. Can I do that without avoiding JSLink for my custom field type, and how? Or do I have to rewrite my custom field so that it doesn't use JSLink?

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I've seen this post but I simply don't have the JSLink option in web part properties for a form created by Sharepoint Designer. Under Miscellaneous, there is only Sample Data, XSL Link, Enable Data View Caching and Send first row... http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117499/how-to-apply-jslink-to-the-custom-new-form-of-list?rq=1

Comment: And when using PowerShell, I get this when I try to set the JSLink property of a field: "The property 'JSLink cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."

Comment: Can you set the JSLink on the WebPart (edit page in browser, not Designer)?

Comment: Yes, if I edit the standard/default New/Edit page from within Sharepoint itself, there is an option for a JSLink. However, it seems to have no effect, I suppose because the JSLink gets tied to the whole webpart rather than to a specific field. Therefore Sharepoint doesn't call the functions it needs to call in this JS, such as the function to obtain the value, initialize element etc.

Comment: Include your CSR code in your question, if you declared the Field correct it overrides <period> CSR is basically: "SP If you are going to display this field [name] then use this JS function for the HTML"

Comment: Yeah, with RegisterTemplateOverrides. But the custom function thus defined is never called. It works fine though when using the default Sharepoint list edit forms, the ones that were not created using Sharepoint Designer.